# What is the integral of $\sin x(1+\sin x)^n$?

Tags: integration

Please help me to compute this integral.
Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Expand $(1+\sin x)^n$ using the binomial theorem and integrate term-by-term, powers of $\sin^k x$, for $k=1, 2, \cdots , n+1$.

Comment: thanks a lot. but how can be computed the integral of $\sin^k x$ in general form?

Comment: Iterate the recurrence relationship $$\int \sin^k x\,dx = -\frac1k \cos x \,\sin^{k-1}x+\frac{k-1}{k}\int \sin^{k-2}x\,dx$$which can easily be obtained by integration by parts

Comment: @Dr.MV.  With due respect, please post this in the solution section so that more people see it.

Comment: @Shailesh As you suggested, I have posted both the outline of the solution provided in my comments and another way forward.

Answer (score 1):

One user suggested that I post my comment as an answer here.  So, to that end, we present herein two approaches.  Both ways forward do require application of [Reduction Formulae for the sine and cosine functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Tables_of_integral_reduction_formulas) and are therefore not truly closed-form expressions.  They can lead, however, to tractable solutions.

**METHOD $(1)$**

Here, we use the binomial theorem to write

$$\left(1+\sin x\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sin^k(x)$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\int \sin x(1+\sin x)^n\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int \sin^{k+1}x\,dx
\end{align}$$

Then, we can use the reduction formula

$$\int \sin^{k+1}x\,dx=\frac{-\sin^k(x)\cos(x)+k\int \sin^{k-1}(x)\,dx}{k+1}$$

and iterate tediously.

---

**METHOD $(2)$**

Another way to approach this problem is to make use of the identities

$$\cos x=\sin (x+\pi/2)$$

and

$$1+\cos x=2\cos^2(x/2)$$

Then, enforcing the substitution $x= y+\pi/2$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\int \sin x(1+\sin x)^n\,dx\\\\
&=\int \cos (y)\left(1+\cos (y)\right)^n\,dy\\\\
&=2^n\int \cos (y)\cos^{2n}(y/2)\,dy\\\\
&=2^{n+1}\int \cos^{2(n+1)}(y/2)\,dy-2^n\int \cos^{2n}(y/2)\,dy \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, we can apply the reduction formula

$$\int \cos^{2(n+1)}(y/2)\,dy=\frac{\sin(y/2)\cos^{2n+1}(y/2)-\frac12(2n+1)\int \cos^{2n}(y/2)\,dy}{n+1}$$

to $(1)$ and iterate.

Comment: Thank you. It helps the community. +1

Comment: @Shailesh And thank you for the +1!  Much appreciative my friend.  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfectly clear what are after. For any given $n$, one could just start to integrate by parts to get an explicit expression, but to have a general expression for any $n$ is different. I assume that you want the latter, and will show you how to get one in terms of the incomplete beta function.

First, we note that with
$$
I(n)=\int (1+\sin x)^n\,dx
$$
what you look for is
$$
I(n+1)-I(n).
$$
Let us find what $I(n)$ is. From $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x=(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)$, we find that
$$
\begin{split}
I(n)&=\int (1+\sin x)^n\,dx\\
&=\int (1+\sin x)^{n-1/2}(1+\sin x)^{1/2}\,dx\\
&=\int (1+\sin x)^{n-1/2}(1-\sin x)^{-1/2}|\cos x|\,dx.
\end{split}
$$
Here, one should perhaps think of what interval one is working on to get rid of the absolute value from $|\cos x|$. In any case, this will cost a $\text{sign}\,\cos x$ outside everything.

Next, we let
$$
u=\frac{1+\sin x}{2}.
$$
Then
$$
du=\frac{1}{2}\cos x\,dx,
$$
and we get that

> $$
> \begin{split}
> I(n)&=\text{sign}\,\cos x\int (2u)^{n-1/2}(2(1-u))^{-1/2}2\,du\\
> &=2^n\,\text{sign}\,\cos x\int u^{n+1/2-1}(1-u)^{1/2-1}\,du\\
> &=2^n\,\text{sign}\,\cos x\,\beta(u,n+1/2,1/2)\\
> &=2^n\beta\Bigl(\frac{1+\sin x}{2},n+1/2,1/2\Bigr)\,\text{sign}\,\cos x.
> \end{split}
> $$

Here, we have used the incomplete beta function,
$$
\beta(x,a,b)=\int x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\,dx.
$$